# jQuery Flowslider, a couple of questions

Tags: jquery, slider

I came upon Flow Slider while searching a jquery scrolling script that will work in desktop and touch devices. It's really amazing, but I have a couple of questions.

First I need the script to be able to drag and touch -I think I managed to do it right-, then I need to start from the start of the div and not from the default position (center).

Second, when I click on an image and try to scroll, it selects all the images and doesn't drag but just scrolls on hover (the default function of flow slider). If I click within the space of the images it works, but this is not right. Here's a demo of the script to see what I mean:

http://www.cre8.gr/gallery/drag.html

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind used another system, as the support for this plugin is not existent!